# Преобразовать динамический массив в статический

Tags: java

Элементами динамического массива являются пары чисел.
Требуется преобразовать его в обычный двумерный массив.
Так выдаёт ошибку во время выполнения ClassCastException:

```
void A(ArrayList<float[]> path) {
    float[][] P=(float[][]) path.toArray();
}
```

Хотелось бы понять почему не работает

Comment: наверно, потому что ты фигню делаешь... расскажи, что у тебя есть и что ты хочешь... сейчас, ты написал метод, который принимает ArrayList<float[]>, в нем лежат массивы чисел и ты их как-то хочешь преобразовать к 2-мерному массиву.. =\

Comment: @Gorets Да, так и есть

Comment: зачем?))))

Comment: Наверно это не лучший способ, хочу передать этот массив в jni на С++.
Наверно лучше развернуть в одномерный массив или буфер

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
float[][] p = path.toArray(new float[path.size()][]);
```